# Grails - Spring Security UI Email for Username

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I'm using Grails 3.2.4 and am attempting to use the email property of my User class as the username for registration.

So far, I've managed to get Spring Security Core to use the email as the username using the configuration setting below:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName='email'
```

However, the registration functionality doesn't seem to take this into account and won't let me register a new user using only an email and password.

I've made a few attempts at overriding the RegisterController but I continue to experience different errors regarding null usernames.

It seems like I must be missing something very simple. Any help / direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: check constraints in User domain class for username attribute - if db already created previously and had been nullable false and you changed to true after - then a manual db upate is needed to alter table change column to be nullable. You are giving an oversight without any actual code or error messages - traces or anything for anyone to give you anything useful on

Comment: Thanks @vahid, No traces were needed for my question as I was asking how to make the registration function in spring-security-ui use the email as a username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that in version **spring-security-ui-3.0.0.M2** the `username` property might not be override-able.

```
String paramNameToPropertyName(String paramName, String controllerName) {
    // Properties in the ACL classes and RegistrationCode aren't currently
    // configurable, and the PersistentLogin class is generated but its
    // properties also aren't configurable. Since this method is only by
    // the controllers to be able to hard-code param names and lookup the
    // actual domain class property name we can short-circuit the logic here.
    // Additionally there's no need to support nested properties (e.g.
    // 'aclClass.className' for AclObjectIdentity search) since those are
    // not used in GSP for classes with configurable properties.

    if (!paramName) {
        return paramName
    }

    Class<?> clazz = domainClassesByControllerName[controllerName]
    String name
    if (clazz) {
        String key = paramName
        if (paramName.endsWith('.id')) {
            key = paramName[0..-4]
        }
        name = classMappings[clazz][key]
    }
    name ?: paramName
}
```

**PS** I'm getting around this now by doing something like this in my user domain class:

```
static transients = ["migrating"]]
String username = null

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email
    this.username = email
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly the information I was looking for.